# Can I switch the hot and cold water supply to improve the pressure of hot?

Tags: water, shower, hot-water, pressure

I have a very old house (built in 1903) with very old and corroded pipes. Because of the corrosion, the hot water pressure is fairly low (mostly in the shower) but cold water pressure is okay. I’m wondering if it would be an okay idea to switch the cold and hot water lines right after the water heater. I think This would drop the cold water pressure which I don’t mind. I know I’ll need to replace all the piping eventually but I’ll probably be selling in the relative near future.

Comment: Why would you not replace the pipes? With a little learning it's not difficult and not much more work than switching them. .

Comment: With the newer plumbing fittings, like push to connect, replacing pipes can be as easy as a putting together a Lego set.  Do you really want to drink water from those old pipes?

Comment: Odds are good that a home inspection will flag the low/mismatched water flow and you'll have to repair it (possibly paying someone else to do so) right before you move out. May as well do it now and get to enjoy a good water flow until you move out.

Comment: @FreeMan It depends on the buyer. I bought a home with this exact problem 5 years ago. I've replaced all the pipes with PEX about 2 years ago. You only have to fix it if you want to sell to a specific buyer or do not want to get low-balled. In retrospect, I should have low-balled by at least 15% but live and learn.

Comment: @crip659 push-to-connect is not compatible with galvanized piping. You would need to properly transition at a threaded joint.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus presumably, the OP is prepared to thread on a couple of flexible supply lines, so he's going to be capable of doing that. Once he's got the appropriate threaded adapters in place, the rest is Sharkbite push on and or PEX crimp on, and both are dead simple. I've been half tempted to replace my perfectly functional CPVC supply lines with PEX because New Tools! and Easy! and Fun! (fortunately(?) the wife remains sane and has put a stop to that idea...)

Comment: @FreeMan What if the blockage is between the end of the PEX and the fixture? :-)

Comment: have you tried using anti-scale overnight? you pour it in your hw heater and let it get into the pipes.  May clog various faucet valves, but if the alternative is repiping, that's not a terrible thing to try.

Comment: You say mostly in the shower.  I assume you've checked for any limiter or partially closed valve on the hot water line?

Answer (score 6):

Your question boils down to "please validate my wonky idea" and I will absolutely **NOT**.

Yes, you can do it but you shouldn't. At best your proposal is something that would be done in a super emergency situation.

---

You ***can*** switch the hot and cold lines at the tank but that would really be quite an obtuse solution. So now your cold valve gives hot water and the hot valve gives cold water? Good luck getting the proper temperature from your shower if you have an anti-scald valve installed.

Sounds like a surefire way to deter the average buyers and lower your home's value.

I think you will find that by the time you've acquired the right tools to perform a wonky cutover then the cost of materials to just do things properly is insignificant.

PEX has made plumbing so easy that it's almost hard to screw up.

Comment: Despite my comment on the OP, I agree 100%. +1

Answer (score 5):

#### No!

This would work fine for your sinks, though anyone who visits would get confused because they would assume "hot on the left, cold on the right". (I learned that years ago from an HVAC supplier who didn't think much of ordinary plumbers - all they need to know is "hot on the left, cold on the right, #()$@(#$% runs downhill". But I digress.)

But it would not work for:

- Washers - though there you can easily swap the connections.
- Dishwashers - normally plumbed (US) to only hot. If connected to cold they would either not work well at all or spend a huge amount on electricity heating water (e.g., from 50 to 140 instead from 120 to 140)
- Toilets - always plumbed to only cold. They would waste a huge amount of energy using hot water.
- Outside faucets - not sure if you use them much, but if you do, I'm not sure your plants will enjoy a hot bath.

Comment: Upvote for pointing out all of the downstream effects like the washing machine, toilet, spigot, etc...

Comment: "downstream" quite literally here.

Comment: dittos on that!  Great answer pointing out all the ramifications of doing this.   To the OP: "Get 'er done and like Freeman said,  enjoy your new plumbing while you're still there .

Comment: I know this is a DIY site but, there are companies in my neck of the woods (PNW) that specialize in re-piping older homes, claiming they can get the work done a just a few days....  Depending upon the skills of the OP and the layout of the plumbing in the house, it could be a big job.  There are probably companies where the OP resides that offer similar services.  It might be better to call a pro and write a check.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson OP hasn't stated their skill level nor budget. Given their proposal I can only assume they're trying to save a dime and do it themselves because I am sure that a plumber would have a hard time keeping a straight face if a client requested such a switchover. To re-plumb an open-basement house would easily run $3,000 or more; and that doesn't even include doing the upstairs which would require opening up walls. Writing a check which is bound to bounce does little good for either party.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  ...mostly agree. I certainly didn't mean to suggest the "switch-over".   And I did couch my comment with *"depending upon skills of the OP and the layout of the plumbing in the house, it could be a big job"* ....maybe a hybrid approach would where they just replace the worst of the worst.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Having performed this exact project 2 years ago I will assure you that it would be next to impossible to guess which section is the "worst of the worst" even for a pro. Water pipe corrosion is an issue on the inside of the pipe so unless you just unscrew one end and have a really long borescope then you're just blindly guessing and wasting your time. In my situation it turned out to be an almost completely sealed up tee shortly before my kitchen and upstairs. There was probably an 1/8th inch of flow in this 3/4 inch pipe.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson By chance this section of pipe and tee was one that I happen to be interested in unscrewing instead of sawzall-ing and the whole thing just broke apart; the pipe thread was left behind inside the tee. Who knows, a few more years and I could have had a swimming pool in my basement :-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  WOW, I've heard of that happening.  Here in the PNW we don't run into very old homes here very often.   We (you & I) are getting snipped here at SE suggesting we move this to "chat" ....so I'll shut up now!  LOL

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson It was a real eye-opener for sure! It's one of the main motivators for suggesting a full replacement instead of a cob-job that will cost more money later on.